# Configuration server problem after changing /tmp mountpoint: how to solve?

Tags: 10.10, fstab, gconf

I created a new partition on my hard drive because my /tmp partition was too small. I changed the mountpoint in `/etc/fstab` and rebooted.

Every time I reboot, I get the following error message at the login screen:

```
There is a problem with the configuration server. (/usr/lib/libgconf2-4/gconf-sanity-check-2 exited with status 256)
```

When I log in, /tmp is mounted correctly and everything seems to work fine.
When I reboot, the error shows again.
When I change the /tmp mountpoint back to the old partition, the error message disappears.

***What could be causing this and how can I solve this issue?***

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This appears to be a sticky bit problem. /tmp needs to have permissions of `1777` (drwxrwxrwt ), please note the last 't' flag.

Compare permissions of `/tmp` using `ls -ld /tmp` with new and old partition and if it is different,

Try changing permissions on new partition.

```
sudo chmod 1777 /tmp
```

Comment: Great to know :)

Answer (score 1):

I guess you deal with a corrupt file system.

Boot from a Ubuntu install disk(flashdrive) and run fsck with the -fy option on your hard drive (/), this will fix several things and cur the error message.

Please let me know, if this fixes your problem!

Regards,
Ilias el Matani